# SharePoint Online search - show only items that are out of folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

Is it possible in SPO search to build a query that will return only documents that are directly in a document library (not in folders)? is there any property that can tell whether specific document is placed in a folder or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use url depth to locate the files in the root of the library

Comment: As I can see, it's not possible to recognize in url which word is a folder name. Subsite, document library or folder name is just a word after \. See below example:

document in root of the library:
https://company.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/Site1/SubSite1/Shared%20Documents/Document.docx?d=wd921dc4370d94076bfd433ceb5298a30&csf=1                  

document in a folder:
https://company.sharepoint.com/:w:/r/sites/Site1/SubSite1/Shared%20Documents/Folder1/December%2012th%202018.docx?d=w7c35912ba617476084861398acbb804c&csf=1

Comment: from above two urls how to recognize that folder1 is really folder name (not a library) ?

Comment: Try to inspect the library in the SharePoint Search Query Tool, and have a look at the managed properties isDocument and UrlDepth. That should be sufficient to pinpoint the documents